Why would someone ever want a horse as their animal companion?
This is something I've been brainstorming for months now. While Horses would obviously have their uses as cheap labor and other non-combat roles, in a world where it's not uncommon to domesticate and train, Large Wolves and Cats, Hippogriff and Griffons among other powerful creatures capable of protecting themselves, why would one ever choose a horse as their primary companion in combat?
Not only does it feel redundant it seems kind of pointless, like choosing to run an outdated build just for the sake of it.

This seems like something that belongs on Roleplaying SE, with an appropriate system tag.  Alternatively, much more detail is required on the world within which the question is set - all you have told us is that there are five different species that are possible animal companions (2 of which do not exist in the real world).  We do not know the environment, tech level, economic background, circumstances of the type of person looking for an animal companion...  Note that if you are asking about a particular person's choice of companion, that is off-topic as being a decision/story element.

There's a story/character-background based possibility. The MC's childhood was adverse, their only friend a horse.... The smell alone of horses makes them feel secure/loved/not alone.

In a world with dogs, elephants, donkeys, pigeons, camels and the many other animals used in combat by humans over the millennia, why would anyone choose the horse? Each has its pros and cons, not the least of which is no animal is universally available to everyone. VTC:Too Story-Based as the pros and cons of each animal are easily researched and the value of those pros/cons is totally circumstance (story) dependent.

Horses have often been trained specifically for combat, have you never seen horses (especially stallions) fight? either each other or dogs or other animals, properly trained one can be far more dangerous than a single wolf .. are you really telling us you have no idea what an accurate hoof to the skull from a large percheron can do to a dogs or wolfs skull? .. go look for some YT videos of donkeys attacking coyotes then scale what you see up to a full size horse in your minds eye.

Some of the various drawbacks of any species can be countered by giving your animal human-like intelligence, and usually the power to communicate mentally. But it doesn't solve everything.

We live in such a world. Horses are cheaper, easier to get and maintain, easier to train, easier to cooperate with, and less likely to kill you or destroy your property than elephants. Elephants are vastly more dangerous in a fight. And it was not uncommon to domesticate and train elephants. But everybody who has had war elephants also had more numerous horse cavalry, and more pack horses than pack elephants.

You ever meet Horse Girls?
Now, I say this as someone who lives in a Rural adjacent area and have several self-confessed Horse Girls as friends - so this comes from a place of love...
Regardless of how expensive, impractical, difficult etc. etc. horses are - they are the type of person that would still choose them as a companion animal
And I have several long-suffering Husbands who are, again, good friends - who will sign-off on that statement whilst laugh-crying at the cost of how Expensive, Impractical and difficult they are to keep.

Several reasons:

horses are (mostly) herbivores. A 500kg warhorse can graze on grass for free, or at worst, require some wheat and occasional apple. a 500kg Lion Mount or a Dire Wolf will eat enormous amount of expensive meat every day. Also, if your horse is hungry, the worst case scenario is that it will help itself to some shrubbery or crash into someone's garden. A hungry wolf will eat its companion, no moral regrets. Even if it wont attack its companion, it can easily snack on passersby, random allies, livestock, and corpses, friend and foe alike.
horses are already herd animals, and thus easy tamable. A horse instinctively understands cooperation and social structure, can be bribed, tamed, or just plain dominated into compliance. Most other pack/herd animals are quite ornery and fight fiercely for dominance. Solitary animals pretty much cannot be really tamed, they do not understand the concept of cooperation.
animals big enough to be rideable, come with a whole host of anatomical issues. Horses too, but we have been breeding them for millennia, and know them in and out. Animal tamers and breeders know how to help an ailing horse, but could very well be unable to to anything to help an ailing direwolf or a griffon. For one, any canine/feline creature big enough to be ridden on will suffer very big problems with their hip joints, due to their own mass, nevermind the extra mass of the rider. Riding a giant wolf, lion, griffon, chimera, etc is an easy way to lame it permanently, and then you have a pet paraplegic predator which drags its useless hind paws behind it. The more "hybrid like" the creature, the worse the issues, because their bodies just plain don't make sense. Anything with both 4 legs and wings is going to suffer tremendous problems with its spine and shoulder hinges for example.
Horses are the right size and shape to ride. A horse is just about as wide as a human can saddle comfortably. Any creature that is narrower or wider than a horse is going to be awkward to ride on. Something winged and lightweight like a hippogriff or a griffon is too narrow to ride on without falling to the side (unless you redesign the saddle to basically be a howdah) and any kind of terrestrial canine/feline/ursine of the right size is going to be enormously broad at the shoulders. It would be like trying to ride a couch.
predators are crap at fighting in battles. Weird as it sounds, predatory animals make crap war mounts. Predators naturally avoid pitched "battles". Their modus of fighting is to take down their prey with as little effort as possible. Predators essentially "assassinate" their prey, and "duel" their competition, they have no natural concept of fighting like a soldier in an unit, against a mass of opponents. Even wolves tend to fight more like guerilla skirmishers than soldiers. Riding one of those into battle is going to be a constant struggle between the rider and its animal mount which disagrees in the tactics they should employ. Horses on the other hand, can be trained to fight like a soldier: go breast-to-breast with the rest of the cavalry, do complex maneuvers in unison, fight with near-berserk rage when surrounded but immediately stop and flee when their rider spurs them to.
arguably, horses, especially trained ones, might make superior fighters even in 1on1 scenario. Sure, a horse-sized wolf will be more dangerous than a horse-sized horse. However, a trained horse will fight bravely and intelligently to the bitter end. Wolves, cats, bears, griffons? They just turn tail and flee when injured. Most predators do not fight to the death, they are too intelligent (or cowardly) to do something this stupid. Horses though, they can fight with a berserk rage rivaling that of an actual bear.
Horses can be kept with other horses. 9/10 of the time, you are not riding your mount companion around, you simply store them at a range or a stable with other mounts. You can keep a 200 horses together, worst case scenario they will fight for dominance some, mostly harmlessly. But you cannot store 20 hippogriffs with 4 griffons, 15 Giant Lions and 50 direwolves, there would be bloodbath.
Stamina. All horses have more or less the same stamina, energy needs and can withstand the same workload. You can have a cavalry unit with 100 horses, and they will be as fast as the slowest horse. But if you have a cavalry unit of a dozen dire-bears, two dozen rideable terrorbirds, and 10 griffins, the griffs will gas out and need rest after a hour or two of travel, terrorbirds will be fainting from sheer exhaustion within half a day,while the bears will barely notice. Inversely though: a freshly rested terrorbird can explode into sprint like a Roadrunner, leaving the Giant Bear in the dust.
finally, horses are cheap, compared to most "exotic" companions. Sure, a horse can only have one foal in a year, while a giant lion can have 6 kittens. But each of this kittens would cost enormous amount of money in feed and keeping, while a foal just needs to follow its mom and graze. A lion big enough to ride would have to eat at least 20 kg of meat a day, just to function, nevermind to be ridden on. This means that your average lion mount companion had to eat the equivalent of about 12 horses before it came of age to be ridden. The horse that can do the same only ate about 3.5 tons of grass and hay to achieve the same body mass. Therefore, a carnivore companion would cost AT LEAST 12 times more than a horse initially, and then just as much to keep.

